# The conditional mean affect variance and covariance

Tags: variance, covariance, means

From [this dicussion](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/45496/33142),

$$
\hat \beta = \frac{\widehat{\mathrm{cov}}(y_i, x_i)}{\widehat{\mathrm{var}}(x_i)}. \tag{3}
$$

$$
\hat \gamma = \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum_i y_i x_i}{\frac{1}{n} \sum_i (x_i)^2} \tag{4}
$$

Comparing $(3)$ and $(4)$, we see that they are the same if the mean of $x$ is zero:  $\frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i = 0$.

How to prove that (3) similar to (4) based on the condition above?

**Updated, what I have tried is:**

(3) can be explained to

$$
\hat \beta = \frac{\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}{\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^2}. \tag{5}
$$

or based on the condition

$$
\hat \beta = \frac{\sum_ix_i(y_i-\bar y)}{\sum_i(x_i)^2}. \tag{6}
$$

while (4) is still the same
$$
\hat \gamma = \frac{\sum_i y_i x_i}{\sum_i (x_i)^2} \tag{7}
$$

So the question that remained here is how to prove

$$\sum_ix_i\bar y=0$$

Comment: Please show us what you have tried or the question will likely be closed.

Comment: Thank @AaronHendrickson, I did update the question, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (6) the term $\sum_i x_i\bar y$ equals zero, because $\bar y$ can be factored out, producing $\bar y\sum_i x_i$.